# uninstalled jre8 to jre6 and having errors

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I just installed jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe from jre-8u101-windows-i586.tar.gz
and I'm having an error when I'm opening Eclipse.

DBGWRAPPER80.DLL MISSING

[image]

and when I press OK another error message appears

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

From the eclipse error, you need Jdk 1.7  to run eclipse mars version.

[JDK requirements for the eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation)

Comment: thank you for the answer :) I'm able to download jdk 1.7 home because the internet at the office sucks lol